# jQuery: How can I know I am calling the right callback inside a function with multiple callback functions?

Tags: jquery, function, callback

I have a function like this

```
$.fn.myFunction = function( options, special, callback ) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        opacity     : '',
        margin  : ''
    }, options );

    //while executing this main function, some cool things happen
    if ( special && typeof special === "function" && things_are_running) { 
        special();
    }

    //when finished executing the main function, there is one more thing
    if ( callback && typeof callback === "function" && things_stopped) { 
        callback();
    }
}
```

and I do some funny stuff like this

```
$('.selector').myFunction( options, function() { /* this is the question about*/ } );
```

How can I know if I am calling the `special()` or the `callback()` function considering only one callback is given?

I should do stuff like this?

```
$('.selector').myFunction( options, function() {}, null );
```

OR THIS?

```
$('.selector').myFunction( options, null, function() {} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but for your first example you can also use

```
$('.selector').myFunction( options, function() {});
```

The function will be assigned to special, in

```
if ( callback && typeof callback === "function" && things_stopped) {
```

callback will be evaluated as false.

Comment: Thank you Barry, I will test ASAP and let you know.